# What is inscribed on Darth Bane's tomb?

Tags: star-wars, darth-bane

In the last episode of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, Yoda goes to Moraband (Korriban) where among other things he encounters the ghost of Darth Bane at his tomb. There is an inscription at that tomb.  Does it have any meaning or it is just random scribbling?

[image: Darth Bane's tomb]

Comment: Open this side up

Comment: *I TOLD YOU I WAS ILL*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Nothing, apparently.

The symbols in the inscription don't seem to quite match any pre-existing Star Wars language, though it most resembles Common Sith.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The StarWars.com page for [the episode](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/sacrifice-episode-guide) is noticeably devoid of an official translation, while [pages](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/lethal-trackdown-trivia-gallery) [for](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/the-zillo-beast-trivia-gallery) [other](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/senate-spy-trivia-gallery) [episodes](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/to-catch-a-jedi-trivia-gallery) [feature](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/sabotage-trivia-gallery) helpful translations of any background writing. This leads me to believe the design is just cool-looking gibberish.

Answer (score 3):

### Gibberish written in "the Old Tongue"

The text seen on this tomb uses a script originally developed in Ralph McQuarrie concept art for the Massassi Temple on Yavin 4, and later established in Canon as used by ancient Jedi and Sith in more recent works (such as *The Old Republic*, *Rebels*, *Resistance*, and *Jedi: Fallen Order*, according to an [unofficial blog post on Numidian Prime about the history of this script](https://numidianprime.wordpress.com/2020/01/31/the-runic-language-of-the-sith/)).

Ahsoka refers to it as "the Old Tongue" in *Rebels*, and it's also appeared in places unrelated to the Jedi and Sith, such as on Boba Fett's throne in *The Book of Boba Fett*. Ochi's dagger in *The Rise of Skywalker* appears to use a close, but non-identical, variant known as "ur-Kittât", according to the Visual Dictionary.

Apparently, the first time it was given an official translation was in notebooks sold at Galaxy's Edge:

[image: Image of a notebook from Galaxy's Edge showing a translation of an alien alphabet into the Latin alphabet]

This key has been used in some official works (Boba Fett's throne, for example, reads "BOBAFETT" forward and reversed), but doesn't appear to have been used for Darth Bane's tomb. Using this key for the runes seen in the episode results in something like:

```
...(G)??TI(P)INIQ?R(K)(B)IC???B?XUV...
...I(A)D(G)IAINZI      VUX?B??ICIB?...
```

(lower right section apparently mirrored from above)

A few characters seem to be present on the tomb's text but not in the key, so it seems to be a slightly different version of the script. It's still possible that the model artists on *The Clone Wars* had some English text in mind when designing the throne, but if so, they didn't use the now-official key.